# How to print the kwargs of django signal?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, signals

I'm sending a signal from a model, the receiver does get the signal but I cannot use the kwargs in the signal. How do I see/print out what's sent in the signal?

```
import django.dispatch

timesheet_signal = django.dispatch.Signal()

def send_timesheet_signal(self, employee, employee_id):
        timesheet_signal.send_robust(sender=self.__class__, employee=employee, employee_id=employee_id)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Timesheet)
def update_employee_info(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    employee    = instance.employee 
    employee_id = instance.employee_id 
    if created:
         ...
```

I tried many shapes and forms, this is the current state of the receiver. How do I see/print out what's sent in the signal?

Comment: `print(kwargs)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kwargs can be thought of as a dictionary, you can solve this in several ways.

```
for k, v in kwargs.items():
    print(f'{k}={v}')
```

or

```
print(kwargs)
```

Some documentation:
[django.db.models.signals.pre_init](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_init)

```
q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

The arguments sent to a pre_init handler would be:

```
Argument    Value

sender  Question (the class itself) args    [] (an empty list      because there were no positional arguments passed to __init__())

kwargs  {'question_text': "What's new?", 'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 26, 13, 0, 0, 775217, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```